# Typus not working in Heroku (error 500) what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Have someone used `Typus` (admin plugin for rails) in `Heroku`?

http://intraducibles.com/projects/typus/install

I follow the instructions and in my local machine (Rails 2.3.5) is working fine, but when I deploy to `Heroku` it crashes.

What I'm doing wrong?

the log:

```
 Logfile created on Mon Mar 29 18:14:06 -0700 2010

Processing TypusController#dashboard (for 190.196.113.93 at 2010-03-29 18:14:07) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"dashboard", "controller"=>"typus"}

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  relation "typus_users" does not exist
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"typus_users"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
):
  vendor/plugins/typus/app/controllers/typus_controller.rb:128:in `verify_typus_users_table_schema'
  /home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:in `call'
  /home/heroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:25:in `call'
  /home/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
  thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
  thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (0.12.6) lib/eventmachine.rb:240:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (0.12.6) lib/eventmachine.rb:240:in `run'
  thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'
  thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/server.rb:150:in `start'
  thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'
  thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/runner.rb:173:in `send'
  thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/runner.rb:173:in `run_command'
  thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/runner.rb:139:in `run!'
  thin (1.0.1) bin/thin:6
  /usr/local/bin/thin:20:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/thin:20

Rendering /disk1/home/slugs/157361_3469154_60b1/mnt/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the typus user table doesn't exist.

Did you migrate on heroku (`heroku rake db:migrate`)? Or use db:push to get your schema pushed up?

edit: add heroku command for migrating

Comment: yes, it worked! thank you very much (I have to wait a few minutes to accept your answer)